# Creating PHP table over SQL-query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, html-table

I want to make an own "google" or an own "wiki" for all the systems we have build in. I have a query which is working when I am executing this on  mysql, it does not react or does not output any data.

I have a textbox for de keyword and a commandbox:

[image: image web overview]

I want to open a new site which, had searched the keyword in my database and gives the correct data in an html-table...

When I am looking at my code, it is looking right.. I do not really know what is wrong.. If someone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
    <title>Wiki Suche</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>Wiki-Suche</b>
<form action='' method ='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='suchfeld' placeholder="z.B. Baan">
    <input type='submit' name='suche_enter' value='Suchen'>
</form>
<hr><br>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['suche_enter'])) {
//Verbindung zum DB
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'normal_user', '', 'Systemuebersicht');
    $suchbegriff = htmlspecialchars($_POST['suchfeld']);
    $suchbegriff = $mysqli->real_escape_string($suchbegriff);

//Error abfangen
    if ($mysqli->connect_error)
        die('Fehler bei der Verbindung: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);


    $sql = '
    SELECT 
hardware_servername.Servername AS "Servername", 
hardware_domaene.Domaene AS "Domäne", 
hardware_betriebssystem.Betriebssystem AS "Betriebssystem", 
Hardware.Lokale_Datenbank AS "Lokale Datenbank", 
Hardware.Datenbank_SQL_Master AS "Datenbank SQL Master", 
Hardware.Instanzname AS "Instanzname", 
hardware_standort.Standort AS "Standort", 
Hardware.Backup_mit AS "Backup mit:",
Service.Servicename AS "Servicename", 
system_systemnummer.Systemnummer AS "Systemnummer", 
system_systemname.Systemname AS "Systemname",
System.Systembeschreibung AS "Systembeschreibung", 
AA.Personen AS "Hersteller",     
AB.Personen AS "Externer Partner", 
system.BKAG_Brugg AS "BKAG (Brugg)", 
System.BCIAG_Brugg AS "BCIAG (Brugg)",  
System.Cables_Diverse_PL_CN_US_DE AS "Cables Diverse (PL, CN, US, DE)", 
System.BINF AS "BINF", 
System.BRAG_Kleindoettingen AS "BRAG (Kleindöttingen)", 
System.BRG_Wunstorf AS "BRG (Wunstorf)", 
System.BGP_Nordhausen "BGP (Nordhausen)", 
System.Pipes_Diverse_FR_PL_IT_US AS "Pipes Diverse (FR, PL,IT, US)", 
System.Ropes_BDAG_Birr AS "Ropes / BDAG (Birr)", 
System.HOLDING_Brugg AS "HOLDING (Brugg)", 
System.BIAG_Brugg AS "BIAG (Brugg)", 
System.BPK_Brugg AS "BPK (Brugg)", 
System.Dritte_Schule_Brugg_LithCom_usw AS "Dritte, Schule Brugg, LithCom usw.",
system_verfuegbarkeitsstufe.Verfuegbarkeitsstufe AS "Verügbarkeitsstufe",
System.Datenverlust AS "Datenverlust",
verantwortlichkeit_rolle.Rolle AS "Rolle",
A0.Personen AS "Hauptverantwortlicher", 
A1.Personen AS "Stellvertretung", 
A2.Personen AS "Wissensträger 1", 
A3.Personen AS "Wissensträger 2", 
A4.Personen AS "Verantwortlichkeit extern", 
Zertifikate.Zertifikatname AS "Zertifikatname", 
Zertifikate.Ablaufdatum AS "Ablaufdatum"
FROM Service
JOIN System ON Service.Servicename_ID = System.FK_Service_ID 
JOIN Hardware ON System.System_ID = Hardware.FK_System_ID 
JOIN Verantwortlichkeit ON System.System_ID = Verantwortlichkeit.FK_System_ID 
JOIN Zertifikate ON System.System_ID = Zertifikate.FK_System_ID
JOIN hardware_servername ON hardware.Servername = hardware_servername.Servername_ID
JOIN hardware_domaene ON hardware_domaene.Domaene_ID = hardware.Domaene
JOIN hardware_betriebssystem ON hardware_betriebssystem.Betriebssystem_ID = hardware.Betriebssystem
JOIN hardware_standort ON hardware_standort.Standort_ID = hardware.Standort
JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS AA ON AA.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = system.Hersteller
JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS AB ON AB.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = system.Externer_Partner
JOIN system_verfuegbarkeitsstufe ON system_verfuegbarkeitsstufe.Verfuegbarkeitsstufe_ID = system.Verfuegbarkeitsstufe
JOIN system_systemname ON system_systemname.Systemname_ID = system.Systemname
JOIN system_systemnummer ON system_systemnummer.Systemnummer_ID = system.Systemnummer
JOIN verantwortlichkeit_rolle ON verantwortlichkeit_rolle.Verantwortlichkeit_Rolle_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Rolle
JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A0 ON A0.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Hauptverantwortlicher
JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A1 ON A1.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Stellvertretung
JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A2 ON A2.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Wissenstraeger_1
JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A3 ON A3.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Wissenstraeger_2
JOIN verantwortlichkeit_personen AS A4 ON A4.Verantwortlichkeit_Personen_ID = verantwortlichkeit.Verantwortlichkeit_extern

WHERE
        hardware_servername.Servername LIKE "%$suchbegriff%"
        OR
        hardware_betriebssystem.Betriebssystem LIKE "%$suchbegriff%"
        OR
        Hardware.Lokale_Datenbank LIKE "%$suchbegriff%"
        OR
        Hardware.Datenbank_SQL_Master LIKE "%$suchbegriff%"
      ORDER BY
      hardware_servername.Servername
      ';

    //Variable erstellen
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");

    echo"<table border='1'>";
    echo "
<tr>
    <td>Systemnummer</td>
    <td>Servername</td>
    <td>Domäne</td>
    <td>Betriebssystem</td>
    <td>Lokale Datenbank</td>
    <td>Datenbank SQL Master</td>
    <td>Instanzname</td>
    <td>Standort</td>
    <td>Backup mit:</td>
    <td>Servicename</td>  
    <td>Systemname</td>
    <td>Systembeschreibung</td>
    <td>Hersteller</td>
    <td>Externer Partner</td>
    <td>BKAG (Brugg)</td>
    <td>BCIAG (Brugg)</td>
    <td>Cables Diverse (PL, CN, US, DE)</td>
    <td>BINF</td>
    <td>BRAG (Kleindöttingen)</td>
    <td>BRG (Wunstorf)</td>
    <td>BGP (Nordhausen)</td>
    <td>Pipes Diverse (FR, PL,IT, US)</td>
    <td>Ropes / BDAG (Birr)</td>
    <td>Holding (Brugg)</td>
    <td>BIAG (Brugg)</td>
    <td>BPK (Brugg)</td>
    <td>Dritte, Schule Brugg, LithCom usw.</td>
    <td>Verügbarkeitsstufe</td>
    <td>Datenverlust</td>
    <td>Rolle</td>
    <td>Hauptverantwortlicher</td>
    <td>Stellvertretung</td>
    <td>Wissensträger 1</td>
    <td>Wissensträger 2</td>
    <td>Verantwortlichkeit extern</td>
    <td>Zertifikatname</td>
    <td>Ablaufdatum</td>
</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "
<tr>
     <td>{$row['Systemnummer']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Servername']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Domäne']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Betriebssystem']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Lokale Datenbank']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Datenbank SQL Master']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Instanzname']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Standort']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Backup mit:']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Servicename']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Systemname']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Systembeschreibung']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Hersteller']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Externer Partner']}</td>
    <td>{$row['BKAG (Brugg)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Betriebssystem']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Cables Diverse (PL, CN, US, DE)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['BINF']}</td>
    <td>{$row['BRAG (Kleindöttingen)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['BGP (Nordhausen)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Pipes Diverse (FR, PL,IT, US)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Ropes / BDAG (Birr)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['HOLDING (Brugg)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['BIAG (Brugg)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['BPK (Brugg)']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Dritte, Schule Brugg, LithCom usw.']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Verügbarkeitsstufe']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Datenverlust']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Rolle']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Hauptverantwortlicher']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Stellvertretung']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Wissensträger 1']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Wissensträger 2']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Verantwortlichkeit extern']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Zertifikatname']}</td>
    <td>{$row['Ablaufdatum']}</td> 
</tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's been ages since I wrote PHP like this, but a form action of `''` doesn't seem likely to do anything to me.

Comment: As always, you could `echo $sql` after defining it and copy/paste in phpMyAdmin or the likes to see if your query is correct and returns any results.

Comment: @Loek it usually means that the form will submit in the same page

Comment: `$POST['suche_enter']` should be `$_POST['suche_enter']`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Okay cool! I thought you had to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for that, which opened like 50 million cans of worms.

Comment: @kerbholz i have changed this part of the code, but it does not change something.. do you/someone have another idea?

Comment: You have an `exit();` in there that terminates the script. You might have forgotten to use brackets for your `if ($mysqli->connect_error)`.

Comment: Now i'm stuck in "$suchbegriff = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST,['suchfeld']);"
the real_escape causel is apparently false... do you have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried using your browser web dev tools to see if any errors are being output to the browser console? Have you tried looking at the PHP error logs to see if anything relevant is being reported?

Comment: re the real_escape issue: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - it expects two arguments when used in the procedural format, the first of which must be the database connection. However you gave it the POST array, which makes no sense. Then the second argument you provide is an arbitrary hard-coded array, which also makes no sense. Also not clear why you used mysqli procedural here when you've used OO syntax the rest of the time.  `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['suchfeld'])` should fix that one. If you don't understand why, ask me.

Comment: ....and as a general point I think you need to study your PHP syntax a little more carefully, and realise that most of the errors you're getting are probably very common and you could paste them into google and get a lot of clues. Plus the docs at php.net are a must-read.

Comment: Also, **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even do this is a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: The output is like following: "mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Users\username\PhpstormProjects\systemuebersicht\Wiki_Suche.php on line 29"

Comment: Based on the code shown above that's impossible: `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST,['suchfeld'])` clearly sends _two_ parameters (`$_POST` is the first, and `['suchfeld']` is the second). Both are incorrect though. See my comments above already for how to fix that.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks ADyson, i do not think to test the "normal user".. I will do this after everything with the root is working once..

Comment: @OkanOG take my advice and change it _now_. Then you only have to re-test what you've already written. If you wait till it's all complete then you have to re-test _everything_ using the new user account. Testing which doesn't take place under real conditions - especially when you _know_ they're not real conditions - is largely a waste of time.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your effort... I have created a user alredy and test everything now with this one.. 
But while I was reading your answers, there plopped a question in my mind.. With ['suchfeld'] I just want to define that the text witch is wridden in the filed "suchfeld" is taken from the code and gives than the correct response..

the linked website of the real escape string, I was visiting there before, but couse of my bad english-understanding i do not understand this completly.. Can you please write to me a solution how I could try to understand this?

Comment: Well I'm not really sure what it is that you don't understand? BTW the PHP documentation is available in a number of different languages, including German (although it appears that sometimes the translations are incomplete, but still it might be helpful)

Comment: Okay, thank you!! You were very helpful. @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson I have fixed yesterday the wrong part of the colde with real_escape_string....
The Webaplication gives no more errors. I can see now the part of the table without the variables, the other part with the relevant data, with the variables i do not see...

Do you or someone have an idea?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars($_POST['suchfeld']);
    $suchbegriff = '$_POST';
    $suchbegriff = $mysqli->real_escape_string($suchbegriff);`... this does not make much sense sense. In particular you never capture the result of htmlspecialchars, so it's pointless, `$suchbegriff = '$_POST';` just assigns a _string_ as the value of $suchbegriff, not the contents of the POST array. So it will mean your query does not match any rows. Try `$suchbegriff = htmlspecialchars($_POST['suchfeld']);  $suchbegriff = $mysqli->real_escape_string($suchbegriff);` You should learn to debug your variable values yourself!

Comment: @Adyson sorry that i am disturbing you, but it does not work. I am trying a lot before i come and ask something..I was googling for 2 hours afther your last reply. I have searched for other techniques to get the Textbox as a variable in my SQL-query but nothing works..  that's the biggest nutcracker for me, i dont know what else i can try.. 
I ask you, maybe you have an idea which I can attach?
Thank you very much for your helpful manner.

Comment: "doesn't work" means what _exactly_? A crash, a warning, unexpected behaviour, what? At what point does it fail? Like I said, _learn to debug_. Go through each step of your process to check if everything's what you intend. e.g. look at your variables - use `echo $_POST["suchfeld"]`; and `echo $sql;` to see whether the input and the SQL query is like you expected. Paste that SQL into MySQL Workbench or PhpMyAdmin and see if it returns the results you expected. Use `var_dump($row);` inside your while loop to see if it has content and what the field names are.

Comment: This is basic, beginner-style debugging. You should be capable of testing your own code. If you're not sure where the problem is, then you break the functionality down into small pieces and verify each part separately by tracing the values of the variables and checking which blocks of code your program executes. That way you narrow down the source of the fault. Using temporary `echo` and `var_dump` statements is a simple but effective way of doing that in PHP, especially if your IDE doesn't have a debugger.  Saying simply "doesn't work" indicates your debugging is not thorough enough.

Comment: @ADyson I do not remember if it was you or I wrote it down. It is so that it does not output any values in the second half of the table, where just the filtered data should be output.
I've already taken apart the SQL syntax, examined the table, but it's most likely that the text box is not perceived as a variable "$suchbegriff". Why that is so I do not understand and therefore I ask so politely. Do you now understand what i am meaning?

Comment: " it's most likely"...it's possible for you (not me, I can't run your code) to be certain, if you follow the kind of debug steps I outlined above.  However I see no reason why it would not recognise the field from the textbox. The textbox has the "name" of suchfeld and that's what you're looking for the in the $_POST field. All very standard and correct. You can verify it, like I said. Also, verifying the the SQL _syntax_ is not the same as finding out what the final real SQL statement created by PHP looks like (after it has inserted the value of $suchbegriff into it).

Comment: Actually I did just go back to the code and notice one thing.... `$sql = '`...you use single-quotes to make your string. And then you do `LIKE "%$suchbegriff%"` within the string. Presumably you hope that PHP will turn `$suchbegriff` into the value contained with that variable. However, it will not, because you used single quotes. For string interpolation (which is what that feature is) to work, the string must be double quoted. Also in my experience MySQL likes _its_ strings to be single-quoted. So I advocate `$sql = "` etc, and `LIKE '%$suchbegriff%'` etc within the query.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing. If you'd followed my advice to actually check the generated value of `$sql` you'd probably have already noticed that it had not replaced the $suchbegriff with the search text. You'd have noticed much quicker than I did having stared at the code for a long time. That is the value of debugging. If you wish to succeed in programming, _please_ go and learn to do it. You will solve problems much quicker than using guesswork, assumptions or relying on others.

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = '`...you use single-quotes to make your string. And then you do LIKE `"%$suchbegriff%"` within the string.

Presumably you hope that PHP will turn $suchbegriff into the value contained with that variable. However, it will not, because you used single quotes. For string interpolation (which is what that feature is called) to work, the string must be double quoted. Also in my experience MySQL likes its strings to be single-quoted.

So I advocate `$sql = "` etc, and `LIKE '%$suchbegriff%'` etc within the query.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing for further detail.